# ASP MVC 3 mobile strategy

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am starting a group uni project and we are using ASP MVC 3. We are going to have a mobile (web) component as well as a "traditional" web app. Some of the views will overlap (as in Incidents mobile view and Incidents ordinary view). ASP MVC 4 has the mobile features that we want, but we don't want to take chances with a Beta version.

What we were thinking of doing was having two MVC 3 projects in our solution, one for the mobile and one for the web app. Alternatively, we were thinking of having some mobile only controllers and having everything in one MVC project. For example (/AccountMobileController/Signup and /AccountController/Signup)?

What do you guys recommend? Is it silly to use ASP MVC 4 Beta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get mobile view support fairly easily in MVC 3. Take a look at how they approached this on Stackoverflow.

http://kevinmontrose.com/2011/07/17/mobile-views-in-asp-net-mvc3/

For the most part, your controllers should be the same for mobile and full site, but the views will be different.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say go for MVC4 Beta.

Although, yes, it is in Beta, it is ALMOST ready for production.

System.Web.Mvc has really not changed that much, and in reality the, "mobile templates" from MVC4 are mostly just Html, Css, and Js templates that come pre-bundled with the templates.

The main new mobile functionality in MVC4 is for swapping out views for different devices.

Plus the Web API is really awesome for creating an API.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features

Comment: I agree that there are no significant changes, but the other group members are worried that ASP MVC 4 RTM will only run on VS 2011.

Comment: It runs just fine on 2010. It is bin deployable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to look at frameworks like Bootstrap and Less, they'll help you build responsive websites without too much effort. Just be careful that you do not inject any css or styles from mvc code as it might interfere with them.